# How to repair Joomla after update crashes?

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I updated my 2 joomla-based web sites today. One functioned fine, the other displayed a popup error message during the backup phase (didn't note the error) and did not complete.

The failed site still works but the administrator page is blank. I enabled error reporting on the admin php page and get:

`Fatal error: Class 'JToolbarHelper' not found in /mnt/web405/a1/78/56896778/htdocs/administrator/components/com_cpanel/views/cpanel/view.html.php on line 36`

I have no idea how to proceed. I have FTP access but that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the update didn't complete, you might try downloading the Joomla upgrade file from https://downloads.joomla.org/, unzipping, and manually uploading via FTP.  If that works in giving you admin access again, go to Extensions->Database->Fix